# Changing SharePoint folder permissions from a CRM process

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm

I have inherited a system with SharePoint 2010 Foundation and Dynamics CRM.  SharePoint is used by our clients to access documents relevant to them, documents are stored in folders by case number in one single list.

As for the CRM side, when a case is created/updated a workflow fires to check if the case principle is a portal user and if so it creates two SharePoint Document Locations - one with a relative URL and one with an absolute URL.  Then an email is sent out that notifies someone on our end that a job has been created for a portal user, that person then goes into SharePoint, finds the job folder, stops inheriting permissions and assigns the user Read permission on that folder.

Server-Based SharePoint Integration was *not* enabled.  The question is, can I programmatically automate the part of the procedure with a CRM process to find the folder on SharePoint, break inheritance and grant the user Read permission?

I have thoroughly poured over the REST API reference materials and don't see anything that I could use to grant permissions or even break inheritance.  Is this even possible with REST API and jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You should try to simplify your post, it's a long one. This guide may help: [ask].

Comment: Also, why the downvotes?  I am just asking for insight from a _helpful_ community!

Comment: The downvotes result likely from the length of the first version and the excess of non essential details. The edit you made improves significantly the content. A downvote doesn't mean the question is not legitimate, it could be because it is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understood everything.... but, would be easier to just set the default permissions as Read only and then just give Write access to the users within your organisation manually, maybe? Then when a case is created for your clients, the default permissions will be Read only, which is what you want?

Anyhow, I can't see changing Sharepoint Permissions from outside Sharepoint (like CRM) as a best practice to be honest... you should avoid that.

If you still want to make those changes, then would be easier by deploying a WCF service on Sharepoint that listens to incoming requests from CRM, sent from either a plugin or workflow... up to you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I can't grant every user read permission because of the sensitive nature of the information in each folder.  I know the situation is really _not_ the way things should be done, but I inherited it that way.  I will look to a WCF service to listen for a CRM Workflow request.

Comment: Welcome. Be aware as well that Sharepoint 2010 uses .NET 3.5 but Dynamics CRM .NET 4.0, so accessing from CRM to Sharepoint wouldn't be a problem (apart from probably how are you going to authenticate), but for the opposite, specially if that is a CRM Online, you might need an interim service that uses .NET 4.0 but that deals with the authentication internally as they can't be consumed from a client using .NET 3.5. Same issue happens between SSIS 2008 and Dynamics CRM.